# Simple BASH string replacement

Tags: string, bash, shell

I'm trying to replace instances of `{$pear_root}` in a config file with the `$PEAR_ROOT` variable in a shell script.

Using the method from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/) under "A Note About Bash Escape Character" I have:

```
ESC_PEAR_ROOT="${PEAR_ROOT//\//\\/}"
sed -i "s/{\$pear_root}/${ESC_PEAR_ROOT}/"../.serverconfig/test.txt
```

I'm getting back **34: Bad substitution** which I think may mean that this is unsupported.

The problem seems to be the use of `s/find/replace/`, as I get the same error whether doing this with `sed` or with `perl`.

What is the simplest way to do this:

```
APP_ROOT=$(php ./scripts/get_realpath.php '../')
PEAR_ROOT="$APP_ROOT/pear"
ESC_PEAR_ROOT="${PEAR_ROOT//\//\\/}"
sed -e "s/{\$pear_root}/${ESC_PEAR_ROOT}/"../.serverconfig/test.txt
```

And end up with all instances of `{$pear_root}` in `test.txt` replaced with the path from `PEAR_ROOT`?

I'm not attached to this method - anything reliable will do.

Comment: what are you trying to set ESC_PEAR_ROOT to instead of PEAR_ROOT?  Can you give an example?

Comment: You haven't escaped the $ in the second part of the expression - does that change things?

Comment: @evil otto: I think the ESC_PEAR_ROOT will end up with \/ where every slash used to be.  I need that for this one statement, but I also need the original PEAR_ROOT for later use.  So if I escape PEAR_ROOT, I won't be able to use it as a path later.

Comment: @John3136: I think I want that to be expanded.  If I escape the $, then the file will end up with $PEAR_ROOT in it instead of the contained path.  I think.  Shell scripting is not my forte =o)

Comment: @evil otto: Oh, you mean what is the path?  In this server it's /var/www/rmc/pear.  The escaped version will be \/var\/www\/rmc\/pear, which should (hopefully) cause the placeholder in the file to be replaced with the unescaped path.  Sorry, I read your last comment as why, not what.

Comment: what is the result of php ./scripts/get_realpath.php '../' ?  It works on my system the way you have it, so I'm thinking it could be that the result of that command is not what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

The problem was:

This:

```
ESC_PEAR_ROOT="${PEAR_ROOT//\//\\/}"
```

Should have been this:

```
ESC_PEAR_ROOT="{PEAR_ROOT//\//\\/}"
```

That was what was causing my "bad substitution" error.

Also, realized I didn't need to escape, since I could just use a different delimiter to s, so I don't even need that line.

Final result ended up as:

```
APP_ROOT=$(php ./scripts/get_realpath.php '../')
PEAR_ROOT="$APP_ROOT/pear"
sed -i "s#{\$pear_root}#${PEAR_ROOT}#g" ../.serverconfig/test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit silly, but I notice you're missing a space between the end of your expression and the name of the file to which you wish to apply it.

```
/tmp $ sed -e 's/{$pear_root}/'"$PATH"'/' test
/tmp $ sed -e 's/{$pear_root}/'"$PATH"'/'test 
sed: bad option in substitution expression
```

Comment: Yes, good catch.  I got that fixed, but the extra "$" is what was killing it.